# /dev/sdb SATA-disk does not even show up in syslogs if I plug it in while machine is running

Tags: syslog

I have Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on an Intel machine:, `uname -a` gives

```
3.2.0-38-generic #61-Ubuntu SMP [..] x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

The mainboard is a Intel S3420GP board.

Until recently, I cannot remember having the following problem, so I think the new behaviour might be from a kernel update?

I have one harddisk `/dev/sda` which is permanently available and works fine.

The machine is used for backup: From time to time, I plug one or two more harddisks in. To do this, the server is equipped with some disk slots where you may pull out or insert a disk tray while the system is running (can we call that "hotplugging" already?).

Obviously, I take care that I unmount any disk properly before pulling it out. I've done this a hundred times before and with other machines, too.

Until some month ago or two, I've always seen a new device `/dev/sdb`, `/dev/sdc` and so on automatically after having plugged in a new disk. The new behaviour is that I'll neither see new devices, nor do I get any hint in the logs when plugging in a harddisk.

How can I tell the machine to recheck for new devices? A command to be executed would be fine to me.

What happened? As I said, I can't remember having had these problems in the last 3 years or so that I use the machine.

Comment: Run the following command `dmesg` before and after you plug the drive in and see if dmesg gives you any information. If it does, paste it here, it can assist us in resolving your issue.

Comment: possible duplicated http://askubuntu.com/q/192461/169736

Answer (score 1):

dmesg did not show any messages, but this info helped greatly:

http://www.makestuff.eu/wordpress/sata-hotplug-in-ubuntu/

In short: We have to tell the SATA controllers to rescan:

```
echo "- - -" | sudo tee -a /sys/class/scsi_host/host2/scan
```